# React router popup windows

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use react router to provide routes for popup windows on my site.

I have core 'dashboard' on which users can click links which open a window above the core dashboard (so the dashboard can be seen beneath the window).

When reading the documentation for react-router I thought this kind of layout was the exact use-case for nested routes but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am testing by having the window be represented by a div with a background color so I can see it.

My routes are configured as such:

```
<Route handler={Application}>
    <Route name='dashboard' path='dashboard' handler={Dashboard} >
        <Route path='window/:id' handler={Window} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

What I expect is that the div appears when I visit /dashboard/window/1 but nothing changes, and looking at the DOM the window div is not even rendered.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the component that you want to nest the view in you need to add a `<RouteHandler />` so that the view is displayed nested in that component. We did something similar but with tabs and wanted to just change the body of the tab and the highlighted tab to get the same effect.

Comment: That worked, oh man, I'm embarrassed that the solution was so simple and I can't even remember the reason I had for thinking that wasn't what to do hahaha. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, we had to figure that one out ourselves, it's not documented at all.

Answer (score 0):

In React Router 1.0 you simply need to add the following to your `Dashboard.render` tree:

```
{this.props.children}
```